# How to do Group By in grails to order by Count(*)

Tags: sql, grails, grails-orm

How do I translate:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, `a` FROM `b` GROUP BY `a` ORDER BY `a`
```

into grails or gorm query?

Comment: how do I order by count? Because of there is no renaming with AS, I cannot write ORDER BY 'count'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

working in grails 1.2.1

```
def c = C.createCriteria()
def pl = c.list {
    projections {
        countDistinct 'id', 'myCount'
        groupProperty 'a'
    }
    order ('myCount', 'desc')
}
```

the answer is for example

```
[[10,a3],[2,a1],[1,a2]]
```

Answer (score 12):

Since grails 1.2 you can create aliases and order by the created alias.

See https://cvs.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-3875 and https://cvs.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-3655 for more details.

Applied to your own code, the HQL query would be :

```
def c = b.createCriteria() 
def results = c { 
  projections {
    groupProperty("a")
    count("a", 'myCount')  //Implicit alias is created here !
  }
  order 'myCount'
}
```

Comment: Thanks this should do it, but as Graeme notes this is moved to grails 1.3
see https://cvs.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-3875?focusedCommentId=200866&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_200866

Comment: You are definitely right! See http://www.grails.org/1.3-RC2+Release+Notes and section and it seems that it is not implemented either in 1.3 (whereas the resolution issue is equal to fixed and Graeme is commenting that code was changed). So I think that you need to make a try :-) (Please keep us informed on the results)

Comment: count("a", 'myCount')

Answer (score 2):

I would try

```
def c = b.createCriteria()
def results = c {
   projections {
      groupProperty("a")
      rowCount()
   }
   order("a")
}
```

Note this is untested.